# Pyodbc returning (Decimal('100.00'),)

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, pyodbc

I'm using pyodbc to read a numeric value from a table, but instead of just giving me '100', it gives me "(Decimal('100.00'),).

Is there a way to get just the number?

I'm running:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT CurrentBalance as Numeric FROM [AccountsQA].[dbo].[AccountBalance] where AccountId = '2000013' and Currency = 'ZAR'")
```

My apologies if this has already been answered, but I haven't been able to find out how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get just the number by doing the following:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT CurrentBalance as Numeric FROM [AccountsQA].[dbo].[AccountBalance] where AccountId = '2000013' and Currency = 'ZAR'")
result = cursor.fetchall()
amount = result[0][0]
```

"result[0]" was returning "(Decimal('100.00'),)", but when I used "result [0][0] it returns only "100.00"

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the table defines that column as `DECIMAL` type, so pyodbc is returning a [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) object to faithfully represent that value.

Assuming that the value may have digits after the decimal point, you could "get just the number" by calling `float()`, but you **don't** want to do that if the column represents money (as the name "CurrentBalance" suggests). Using `float` values to represent money is a **Bad Idea**.

Instead, you should probably just continue to use the value as a Decimal.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is almost three years old, but in case it helps anyone else searching, my suggestion would be to import Pandas and use that to parse through it.  This approach has helped me on several occasions.

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=YourServer;'
                      'Database=YourDatabase;') 
##this is for trusted connection.  
###You may also need to add  Username and password for your code

data = pd.read_sql_query(("SELECT CurrentBalance as Numeric FROM [AccountsQA].[dbo].[AccountBalance] where AccountId = '2000013' and Currency = 'ZAR'"), conn)

print(data.CurrentBalance[0])
```

This will give you the value of the first response in the CurrentBalance column.

Answer (score -1):

It would be cleaner to take care of it in your query from the start:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT CAST(CurrentBalance AS INTEGER) AS Numeric FROM [AccountsQA].[dbo].[AccountBalance] WHERE AccountId = '2000013' AND Currency = 'ZAR'")
```

Comment: Yes it would, assuming that the values in that column really are integers. If not, then `CAST(... AS INTEGER)` would result in even worse "rounding error" than converting it to `float`.